# C: access to dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, vector, dynamic

I'm trying to print a variable in my dynamic allocated array, but it returns a wrong value.

This the the array declaration:
`int16_t *sample_vector = malloc (num_samples*sizeof(int16_t));`

And the print attempt

```
sample_vector[i] =  data_buffer[0] | 
               (data_buffer[1]<<8) | 
               (data_buffer[2]<<16)| 
               (data_buffer[3]<<24);

printf ("Sample vector [%ld]: %d\n", i, sample_vector [i]); //this works fine, it prints shows the real sample value

printf ("Sample vector [%ld]: %d\n", (i-1), sample_vector [i-1]); //this doesn't work, it prints garbage
```

Comment: Where is `i` defined?

Comment: Also you're printing `short`s, use the `%h` conversion specifier.

Comment: `i` is defined inside a `for (i = 0; i < num_samples; i++)`

Comment: When `i == 0`, `sample_vector[i-1]` accesses outside the array, producing undefined behavior.

Comment: Unless you have some other problem, the code should work properly when `i > 0`.